cAdvisor reports high WSS, but low RSS and cache memory usage
I observed the following cAdvisor memory metrics for a container deployed in Kubernetes Service on Azure and am struggling to come up with an explanation. It's a .NET 6 program running in the container by itself and there's only 1 container in the pod.



Metric
Size




container_memory_usage_bytes
3247980544 (3097 MB)


container_memory_working_set_bytes
3234648064 (3084 MB)


container_memory_rss
336674816 (321 MB)


container_memory_cache
14274560 (13 MB)



Basically the total memory usage and WSS are both very high (~3 GB), but RSS and page cache usage are both quite low (~300 MB and ~13 MB respectively). These stats were more or less constant for a long time (i.e. they are not short-lived spikes).
My very crude understanding of these metrics and Linux's memory management is that RSS is basically the amount of memory actually allocated by the program (e.g. stacks, heaps and stuff that the typical app developers are familiar with). WSS should basically be RSS + active page cache (file cache that Linux considers to be in active use). And container_memory_cache is basically active page cache + inactive page cache (file cache that Linux considers to be inactive and might be evicted first in case of memory pressure).
So I can't see how WSS (3 GB) can be so much larger than RSS + page cache (300 MB + 13 MB). What's likely taking up all the memory space as indicated by WSS metrics? I read somewhere that WSS also includes kernel memory but that can't possibly take up 2.7 GB?. My program is a regular ASP.NET Core WebAPI and both the container_memory_mapped_file and container_memory_swap metrics are zero throughout the period.
Appreciate if someone can point out if my understanding is wrong and how to possibly explain these metrics. Thanks a lot!

The high WSS compared to RSS and cache can be attributed to a combination of shared memory usage, .NET runtime memory management, and garbage collection behavior. If the container's processes are utilizing shared memory with other processes or containers, this would be included in WSS but not in RSS. .NET applications, especially ASP.NET Core, often rely on shared libraries and runtime components which can contribute significantly to WSS without being fully reflected in RSS. Then there is runtime's garbage collector's retained memory can also contribute to a higher WSS.

You can use tools like dotMemory or PerfView to profile the memory usage of your .NET application. This can provide insights into how memory is being allocated and retained. You can even use Linux command like ipcs to list shared memory segments and determine if your container is using shared memory extensively.

MS provides documents to monitor memory which you can go through for references:

Monitor your Kubernetes cluster performance with Container insights
Troubleshoot Azure Cache for Redis server issues
WSS and RSS K8s


I see you have asked the same question on  https://serverfault.com/questions/1162727/high-wss-but-low-rss-and-cache-memory-usage-in-kubernetes-reported-by-cadvisor

@Arko thanks a lot for the suggestions. The .NET program is self-contained (i.e. built with all its dependencies in the container) and considering that there's only 1 process in the container and 1 container in the pod, I think shared memory by the runtime can be ruled out. A memory dump of the process shows a quite small memory usage (~800 MB). The difference between this and RSS is likely due to the .NET runtime being loaded into memory.

But the main puzzle is why WSS is taking up so much space, considering that both RSS and .NET memory dump are much smaller. I guess a possible cause is active file cache if my program was actively using files to cache data...

Coming from a Windows background (where OS file cache does not count towards any process-level memory metric), the way Linux measures memory usage does take some time to get used to, and makes it difficult to compare metrics across operating systems (maybe this doesn't make sense in the first place?)
